# Нет никаких данных после POST-запроса

Tags: php, post, xmlhttprequest, xhr

Здравсвтуйте.
Задача состоит в следующем.
1. Есть страница index.php, в ней выполняется функция, показанная на картинке.
2. Внутри функции генерируется скрипт, внутри которого создается запрос, ну и, собственно, затем он посылается на сервер.
3. Посылаться он должен со страницы index.php на неё саму же.
4. Но при вар дампе массив POST пустой.
Вроде бы все по правильному, по мануалам делаю, но ничего не выходит. Видимо, как-то не так оно работает. Помогите, пжлст)

```
public static function getUserVisitTime()
    {

            echo '<script type="text/javascript">'
                . 'let time = new Date().toLocaleTimeString().slice(0,-3);'
                . 'const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();'
                . 'const body = "time=" + encodeURIComponent(time);'
                . 'xhr.open("POST", "http://localhost/avmaka/index.php", true);'
                . 'xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");'
                . 'xhr.send(body);'
                . '</script>';
            var_dump($_POST);


    }
```

Comment: Вопрос должен содержать минимально воспроизводимый код _(а не скриншот!)_

Comment: @Эдуард поправил

Comment: http://phpfaq.ru/newbie/na_tanke